# Fill formula containing named range but change named range based on relative reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, named-ranges

I have a formula that I need to copy in many cells, but I don't know how to copy a named-range reference to another cell without changing it.

NamedRange (a table imported from database connection) would look like

```
Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|
Data|Data|Data|Data|
Data|Data|Data|Data|
```

Formula example:

```
=SUMIFS(NamedRange[Col1], NamedRange[Col3],$A3...)
```

If I copy this, for example, in different columns, the "Col1" would change to the "Col2" and "Col3" would change for "Col4".

After filling the formula over to the right, it would give:

```
=SUMIFS(NamedRange[Col2], NamedRange[Col4],$A4...)
```

How can I copy it without changing?

The exact formula, to give a better idea... Here is the formula of 1 cell:

```
=SUMIFS(Table_sql.project.com_wf_tbl_Rainbow_LeaveRegister[BO Code],Table_sql.project.com_wf_tbl_Rainbow_LeaveRegister[Process Status],"completed",Table_sql.project.com_wf_tbl_Rainbow_LeaveRegister[Employee No],$A10,Table_sql.project.com_wf_tbl_Rainbow_LeaveRegister[First Day of Leave],"<="&C$9,Table_sql.project.com_wf_tbl_Rainbow_LeaveRegister[Last Day of Leave],">="&C$9)
```

Comment: Are you sure? What is the exact named range name? I tried it and the named range remains the same when I copy the formula to another column?

Comment: Please post the exact formula you are using and post the formula that defines the named range. A range name normally does not change when copied to a different cell. Then, again, a range name can be defined with relative references, in which case, it WILL change when copied somewhere else. So, to help us troubleshoot, please provide more detail.

Comment: It's not the "NamedRange" that changes.

In Excel Now you can use the "Column Reference" of a NamedRange to create an array inside the NamedRange so in the formula Above

NamedRange[Col1Reference] would refer to the column "Col1Reference" when I drag it, it will give "NamedRange[Col2Reference] (the 2nd column in the range) Then so on... Once at the last column if you keep dragging it will go with the first Column again.

Comment: Use the `$` char before the column letter, such as `$A1`. You can do this with `F4`.

Comment: ... I'm not talking about cell reference but with NamedRange Reference...

Comment: Moderators cannot do anything about this, so please don't use flags for getting attention to your question. My tip would be to edit your question with your recent progress. That way it's bumped to the front page. Other than that, there's not a lot that can be done if you do not have the reputation yet to place bounties, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is just to copy the text in the formula bar and pasting it back there after selecting a new cell.

Comment: Yeah I was looking for an easy Way ;-) But thanks ehehe I have 180 cells wide spreadsheet hehe

Answer (score 0):

Select the cell with the original formula, copy it, select the range of cells that you want to have the same formula, and paste it.

For some reason, "filling" a formula will make the column reference move, but pasting into a range of cells will preserve the original column reference.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 4 years too late, but an alternative to keeping the range references constant in the formula is to use the [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) function. This thread showed up when I was searching for something similar for myself.

With your example, the SUMIFS would look like this

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("NamedRange[Col1]"), INDIRECT("NamedRange[Col3]"),$A3...)
```

Hoping this answer would help others who require the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something like the `$` sign in a named reference, then you could refer to a named reference column by defining it as a range:

```
=SUMIFS(NamedRange[[Col1]:[Col1]],...)
```

This will be a column range, which start and ends at `Col1` column of `NamedRange`. Copying this formula using the bottom-right corner of the cursor will retain this reference, and every new cell will contain `NamedRange[[Col1]:[Col1]]`. This also works with the current row:

```
=NamedRange[@[Col1]:[Col1]]
```